# AWS Cognito - Enabling MFA for a user pool user

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm having trouble enabling multi factor authentication for a AWSCognitoIdentityUser.  The snippet below runs without error, but fails to update the user to MFA enabled in the AWS console.

Our user pool is set to MFA optional.  We can manually enable a user, but not through the app (swift 3)

Any help would be appreciated!

```
    self.user = self.pool?.currentUser()

    let mfaOptions = AWSCognitoIdentityUserMFAOption()

    mfaOptions.attributeName = "email"
    mfaOptions.deliveryMedium = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderDeliveryMediumType.email

    let settings = AWSCognitoIdentityUserSettings()
    settings.mfaOptions?.append(mfaOptions)


    self.user!.setUserSettings(settings).continueWith( executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task: AWSTask!) -> Void in

        print(task.debugDescription)

        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            print("error")
        } else {
            print("updated 2 factor")
        }


    })
```

Got some help on this from someone on the Cognito git hub site.  Thanks behrooziAWS!

settings.mfaOptions is nil so appending to it is a noop. Try setting it to an array instead of appending to a nil array:

settings.mfaOptions = [mfaOptions]

That did the trick.